# getting rid of % from string php/codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi I am getting a string like this `FI64%201660%203000%201176%2025`
and I am trying to remove those % before putting it into the database I tried, both `$str=preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $str);`
`$string = str_replace(" ", "", $string);`
but did not work, So need help to remove those % from the string. I guess they are basically blank spaces from the input field.

Answer (score 1):

Your string is url encoded (You need to replace `%20` instead of only `%`, and yes, it's blank space). User urldecode for that:

```
echo urldecode('FI64%201660%203000%201176%2025');
//FI64 1660 3000 1176 25
```

Comment: So can I write it like this
$IBAN = urldecode($iban); ??

Comment: @Aurora Yes if you have `$iban` variable defined

Comment: $iban is basically the string of 'FI64%201660%203000%201176%2025'

Comment: Thanks :D I will accept your answer after the timelimit is over